# How to play webm in Android.Media.Mediaplayer? (error (1, -2147483648))

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to stream webm (opus) audio in my Xamarin Android App but I keep getting a UNKNOWN_ERROR by preparing the player.
My code looks like that:

```cs
    public class AndroidAudioPlayerHelper : AudioPlayerHelper {
        private readonly Media Player player;

        public AndroidAudioPlayerHelper() => player = new MediaPlayer();

        private void PlayNew() {
            player.Prepared += (sender, e) => {
                                   player.Start();
                               };
            player.PrepareAsync();
        }

        public override void PlayStream(string url) {
            player.SetDataSource(url);
            PlayNew();
        }


    }
```

My url looks like `http://localhost:9001/api/v1/song/stream/00000000000000000000000000000000`.
And everything is working fine when I point on a mp3-file or use my UWP-App.

I already tried to set AudioAttributes but it didn't work either.

Comment: If you are using a newer version of Android, your resource has to be a https resource, or allow insecure connections in your manifest. Otherwise you might be missing the codec to decode OPUS.

Comment: thank you, its workin with the android:usesCleartextTraffic="true". You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a newer version of Android, your resource has to be a `https` resource, or allow insecure connections in your manifest.

Try adding: `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to your `Application` node in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

This should preferably be disabled for release builds when you have a properly configured server.